# Tableau Online Can't Connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I'm new to postgres and computer networks, so I'm having a hard time with this problem.
I installed postgres via Homebrew on my mac recently. Up to now I could create a user on postgres and use psql as well as connect with pgAdmin.
I'm now trying to connect PostgreSQL with Tableau Online to deliver some analysis but it keep giving me this error [Tableau Online screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA2so.png).
Does anyone know what it might be?
I already changed postgresql.conf line:

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

to

```
#listen_addresses = '*'
```

and added the following line on pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all     all     all         md5
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Dont forget to remove the `#`  -->> `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I removed the `#`, but it still gives me the same error. Do you know what else it might be?

Comment: Did you restart the Postgres service after editing?

Comment: I stopped and started postgres with homebrew. Does it need to be done in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau Online is a cloud service. Machine where Tableau is running is not your mac, but actually some box somewhere in tableau cloud. By stating localhost you tell tableau to connect to postgres to that box. Which is not correct in this case. In order to connect to your postgresql you need to tell to Tableau Online the actual public ip address where postgresql server is.

So you need to figure out your postgresql public ip address e.g google "what is my ip"... there is few services available

Then give that address to Tableau public. Next thing is the firewall etc settings on your mac. I suggest you do some study what is safe and what not. But in general you should allow incoming connections from Tableau Online IP address.

Pls. note that your mac public ip will change when you use different network(wifi) and even time to time on same network. Normally servers like postgresql in production environment have static ip address.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer :)
I checked what is my public IP address  on "what is my ip" and put it as the server address on Tableau Online field. I also checked my firewall, and it is turned off. But I still receive the same message. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: Is it even possible to connect from "The Internet" to your local Mac? Usually you are behind a router, and have only a private IP assigned.

Comment: Connection form "The internet" is possible but needs to conf the routers(if possible), to allow incoming connections from Tableau online IPaddr targeted to postgres port. Routers normally have rules for forwarding. There could be multiple routers in the network your mac is connected to. Some of the routers might be on the ip network provider side. I would try 2 things, use traceroute from mac to internet and e. g. https://ping.eu/traceroute/ from internet to your mac. Second thing i would try is to use pgadmin on another pc to test is it able to connect to your mac using same wifi network.

Comment: I tried the approach you said about traceroute. When I do it from my mac, I can see the addresses the packages flow until they reach the internet. When I use ping.eu/traceroute though it doesn't reach my public ip address. It get stuck before the router. Do you think it might be the router configuration of the firewall?

Comment: Yes i do. Can you connect locally using another pc/mac? e.g pgadmin and same wifi & local IP's. Routers by default do not accept incoming. And it is a good security feature to deny malicious attempts. Do not configure your router/firewall if you are not sure what might happen. Configuring can be tricky so for to be on the safe side get local help. And there could be routers/firewalls in your network provider infra and those you cannot configure by yourself. Maybe your network provider could help setting the port forwarding and open port for postgresql + whitelist Tableau online public IP